# Changing PHP default timezone not working

Tags: php, date, timezone

I am trying to have a line of code added to an html document that is preceded by the time. I want the time zone to be relative to me, however I cannot change it from the default UTC. I have changed in the php.ini file to PST as well as using date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); and yet it still prints the time 7 hours ahead of my timezone. Heres the code that deals with the time:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['name']))
{
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

    $msg = $_POST['text'];

    $fo = fopen("log.html", 'a');
    fwrite($fo, "<div class=msgln>(".date("g:i A").") <b  style=color:red;>".$_SESSION['name']."</b>: ".stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($msg))."<br></div>
    ");
    fclose($fo);
}
```

Comment: Lost FTP connection and the file failed to update. I didn't see this and was wondering why it didn't make any difference.

Comment: At which point did this not work? Just curious so we know what fixed your immediate problem.

Comment: Heres basically what happened, I was editing the code on my local computer and saving is supposed to just auto-uploade/overwrite the preexisting file, however my connection was lost(wifi dropped dead for a second or something) and when i saved instead of connecting, it just saved the file to my hard drive. I just reconnected and uploaded the file and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Servers should be set to UTC, and you should not be looking to change the default.  Instead, what you want to do is create a DateTime object based on the time, then convert it to the timezone you want, and display.

```
$now = new DateTime();
$now->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
echo $now->format('g:i A');
```

I don't know if your format string is valid or not, but the format method is suppossed to be compatible with that accepted by the date() function you were using in your original example.

Comment: Even though this didn't answer the question it is the proper way to do this so in case anyone else comes across this post i will mark yours as correct.

Comment: I don't know if I'd say *should*, but using UTC does make some time-based tasks a bit easier. Then again, all you really need is an accurately-recorded time which can then be easily translated if necessary. I totally agree, however, that what you don't want to do is regularly change the server time/timezone as part of script execution.

Comment: Although if we're talking RFC language I guess *should* is appropriate ;) ... good discussion on using and saving time here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2532729/264628

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you're using a valued timezone. You can find a [list of supported timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) in the PHP docs.

The second problem is using [date()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) without specifying the timestamp. This defaults to the timestamp produced by [time()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) which (based on a comment in the documentation) is UTC time. You'll either have to use [strftime()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) or manually subtract the difference from UTC.

Comment: Oh right, i also tried America/Los_angeles and that didn't work as well

Comment: Capitalization issue? The list says *America/Los_Angeles*

Comment: Copy and pasted straight off the site so wasn't that. Everywhere i've read it says this is how you are supposed to do it, but its not working?

Comment: Don't know if this comment is still relevant: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php#100220

Comment: Looking into it I came across this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php and it appears that this function has some issues with cross platform. What would be the best way to just subtract 7 hours from the hour?

Comment: Unless you're designing for cross-platform support (or developing on different platforms) I wouldn't worry about that.

Comment: However, you can calculate a 7-hour difference. `time()` returns the time in seconds, so `time()-(7*60)`

Comment: I just found out the source of my error. my ftp connection was lost and everytime i went to save it just saved the temp file and not actually update on my server. I re-established connection and uploaded the file and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you use 'etc/GMT' you can set the dateTime object to the desired time zone like so:

```
$dtz = new DateTimeZone('etc/GMT-10');
$dt = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d h:i A"), $dtz); 
$date = gmdate("Y-m-d h:i A", $dt->format('U'));
```